# Why is Kenny G portrayed as a homosexual in southpark in the last episode of season 3?

Tags: character, south-park

I recently started watching South Park episodes and in the final episode of season 3 (Worldwide Recorder Concert), Kenny G is shown as kissing the teacher Garrison. I thought Kenny G might be gay in real life but when I checked he is straight. Why would the show creators would do like this?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I'm guessing it's because you're asking for an opinion based answer.

Comment: Mmm - I don't think its necessarily opinion only, there may be a well known reference, or something said by the makers of South Park.

Comment: Probably, simply because the makers of South Park don't like Kenny G. Why do you think they made Barbara Streisand evil ?

Comment: Add to that the fact that they even made Richard Dawkins gay for an episode and you realize that sometimes Trey Parker and Matt Stone just do things which are not meant to be explained

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to his appearance and 'G' in his name, Kenny G is always targeted for being a a Gay. But the G stand for Gorelick because his real name is  Kenneth Bruce Gorelic.

Even he got [Wikipedia controversy](http://onerudedude.blogspot.in/2008/12/kenny-gs-wikipedia-article.html), which I don't know is real or not but surely got speculated on internet. So I think South Park doesn't made it all on their on but used the controversy associated with the actor for their own good.